# Strange syntax errors with with_sequence

Tags: ansible, jinja2

The code is this:

```
- name: Enable monitoring ports (SELinux)
  firewalld:
    ports: "{{ _loadbalancer_https_stat_base + item|int }}"
    proto: tcp
    setype: http_port_t
    state: present
  become: yes
  with_sequence:
    count: "{{ __loadbalancer_processor_count }}"
  notify: Restart firewalld
```

The error I get is:

```
fatal: [loadbalancer.vbox]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "unknown error parsing with_sequence arguments: u'count'. Error was: unrecognized arguments to with_sequence: [u'_raw_params']"}
```

I've tried some alternate syntaxes:

```
  with_sequence:
    - count: "{{ __loadbalancer_processor_count }}"
```

Which gives:

```
fatal: [loadbalancer.vbox]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "unknown error parsing with_sequence arguments: {u'count': 4}. Error was: expected string or buffer"}
```

And:

```
  with_sequence: "count={{ __loadbalancer_processor_count }}"
```

Which gives:

```
failed: [loadbalancer.vbox] (item=1) => {"failed": true, "item": "1", "msg": "unsupported parameter for module: proto"}
failed: [loadbalancer.vbox] (item=2) => {"failed": true, "item": "2", "msg": "unsupported parameter for module: proto"}
failed: [loadbalancer.vbox] (item=3) => {"failed": true, "item": "3", "msg": "unsupported parameter for module: proto"}
failed: [loadbalancer.vbox] (item=4) => {"failed": true, "item": "4", "msg": "unsupported parameter for module: proto"}
```

The relevant documentation gives either the sequence notation or the key=value notation. None of these are working and it's not at all clear why. Searching for these errors on Google is turning up nothing similar.

Comment: The last syntax DOES work. The error is with the task, which I can fix. However, I want to understand why the other two syntaxes don't work, especially with the second one being explicitly documented.

Comment: This is all correct YAML so the problem purely exists at the level of how Ansible interprets the value of `with_sequence` (resp. a mapping, a list of a mapping, a scalar). Have you tried these syntaxes with hard-coded values instead of `{{ }}` (i.e. making sure there that jinja2 is not breaking things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with_sequence` doesn't accept parameters as dict, only as **string**!
Either in shortcut format `[start-]end[/stride][:format]`,
or in `key=value` format `start=5 end=11 stride=2 format=0x%02x`.

Shortcut syntax is broken (seems long ago). I'll make Issue/PR to fix it.

You can inspect code for [documentation](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/1acb29ff9b684d168de3e14c2a0f5fdf0ee2b9eb/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/sequence.py#L43-L77) and parameters [parsing](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/1acb29ff9b684d168de3e14c2a0f5fdf0ee2b9eb/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/sequence.py#L187-L188):

So only valid syntax for you is (as per current Ansible ver 2.2.1):

```
with_sequence:
  - "count={{ __loadbalancer_processor_count }}" # one sequence
  - "count={{ another_count }}" # another sequence in the same loop
```

or

```
with_sequence: "count={{__loadbalancer_processor_count}}" # single sequence
```

Update: [Issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22988), [PR](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/22989)

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if the documentation properly indicated this. I was able to get it to work using the KVP syntax.